# Reading RequestMapping wildcard in webflux application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to obtain the wildcard value from a controller's `@requestMapping` within a Spring boot webflux application:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/template/**")
public class TemplateController {
    @GetMapping
    public Mono<String> getTemplate ( ... ) {
        String path = ...     // obtain the value of ** in the @RequestMapping
        return Mono.just(path);
    }
}
```

Everything I have found regarding reading such a value is for an MVC application; those solutions don't work for a webflux application.

How does one access this value within a webflux context? I would prefer an annotation-based approach for reusability, but any solution would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the path from `ServerHttpRequest` that could be obtained from `ServerWebExchange` passed to the controller method. From `ServerHttpRequest` you can get access to a structured representation of the **full** request path

```java
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
public Mono<Void> endpoint(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = serverWebExchange.getRequest();

    RequestPath path = request.getPath();
    String value = path.value();

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

With this you can play around the methods of `RequestPath`, maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks. And from investigating `RequestPath`, the tweak to produce exactly what I was after is `request.getPath().subPath(2).value()`.